# How to search ElasticSearch via NEST and filter results for distinct entries on custom Property

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST in a .Net application that, among other things, tracks locations and stores them in ElasticSearch. These TrackedLocations (see simplified model below) all have an UserId and there will many such indexed TrackedLocations per UserId.

Now what I want to find and query for is all the TrackedLocations nearby a given Lat/Lon and radius combination but I only want the most recent one per user... so basically perform a 'distinct' filter on the UserId, sorted by LocatedAtUtc.

I could certainly get all documents and post-process / filter these via i.e. Linq etc but if Nest/ES can do that natively, I'd certainly prefer it that way.

One variation of that query is a mere count of these distinct instances, as in.. how many of these (distinct per user) are there at any given lat/lon/radius?

The Model(s) look similiar to this:

```
public class TrackedLocation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public MyLocation Location { get; set; }
    public DateTime LocatedAtUtc { get; set; }
}

public class MyLocation
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Lon { get; set; }
}
```

.. the MyLocation type is just there for clarification.

Is that possible via ES / Nest queries and if so, how?

Comment: Hi Jörg. may you post sample query which you tried? I'm interested in how do you search.

Comment: Mapping is also important if you have a parent>child relation setup in elasticsearch between User>TrackedLocation then you should be able to what you want using [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-inner-hits.html) which NEST fully supports

Comment: @MartijnLaarman these TrackedLocation documents are not in a parent > child relationship from/to any User Documents and don't need to be from the applications point of view (the app does not require search for users).. I merely want to filter down to exactly one 'Most recent' per .UserId, if any.

Comment: What I am looking for sounds a lot like top_hits (http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/aggregations/top-hits.html) which the website says is not implemented yet, but it looks like it already is (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/940)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @MartijnLaarman 's initial suggestion and after reading a bit more regarding Aggregations' Memory Consumption, I decided to try out the Parent/Child approach he suggested and here's the same result as I wanted.. without using Aggregations but mere Filters over a Parent/Child relationship.

The Models are setup similarly like this now:

```
elasticClient.CreateIndex(indexName, descriptor => descriptor
    .NumberOfReplicas(0)
    .NumberOfShards(1)
    .AddMapping<User>(new RootObjectMapping // I use TTL for testing/dev purposes to auto-cleanup after me
    {
        AllFieldMapping = new AllFieldMapping { Enabled = false },
        TtlFieldMappingDescriptor = new TtlFieldMapping { Enabled = true, Default = "5m" }
    },
    userDescriptor => userDescriptor.MapFromAttributes())
    .AddMapping<TrackedLocation>(new RootObjectMapping // I use TTL for testing/dev purposes to auto-cleanup after me
    {
        AllFieldMapping = new AllFieldMapping { Enabled = false },
        TtlFieldMappingDescriptor = new TtlFieldMapping { Enabled = true, Default = "5m" }
    },
    trackedLocationDescriptor => trackedLocationDescriptor
            .MapFromAttributes()
            .Properties(propertiesDescriptor => propertiesDescriptor
                .GeoPoint(geoPointMappingDescriptor => geoPointMappingDescriptor.Name(post => post.Location).IndexLatLon()))
                .SetParent<User>())); // < that's the essential part right here to allow the filtered query below
```

When indexing new TrackedLocation instances I set the Parent (User) like this:

```
elasticClient.Index(trackedLocation, descriptor => descriptor
                    .Index(indexName)
                    .Parent(parent.Id.ToString()));
```

And the actual filtered query looks like this:

```
    var userIdsFilteredQueryForLast24HoursAndLocation = elasticClient.Search<User>(search => search
        .Index(indexName)
        .MatchAll()
        .Source(false)
        .TrackScores(false)
        .Filter(outerFilter => outerFilter.HasChild<TrackedLocation>(childFilterDescriptor => childFilterDescriptor
            .Filter(filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor
                .And(
                    andCombinedFilter1 => andCombinedFilter1
                        .Range(dateRangeFilter => dateRangeFilter
                            .GreaterOrEquals(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))) // filter on instances created/indexed in the past 24 hours
                            .OnField(trackedLocation => trackedLocation.CreatedAtUtc)),
                    andCombinedFilter2 => andCombinedFilter2 // and the second filter here is the GeoDistance one.. 1km away from a given .Location(...,...)
                        .GeoDistance(trackedLocation => trackedLocation.Location, geoDistanceFilterDescriptor => geoDistanceFilterDescriptor
                            .Distance(1, GeoUnit.Kilometers)
                            .Location(37.809860, -122.476995)
                            .Optimize(GeoOptimizeBBox.Indexed)))))));
```

So the raw request looks like this:

```
{
  "track_scores": false,
  "_source": {
    "exclude": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "trackedlocation",
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "createdAtUtc": {
                  "gte": "2015-07-18T08:58:02.664"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "location": "37.80986, -122.476995",
                "distance": 1.0,
                "unit": "km",
                "optimize_bbox": "indexed"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The search itself is towards User instances combined with a .HasChild filter.. which then again is the same logic as the Aggregation one (by day and location).

So an example, raw response looks like this:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sampleindex",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "54ccbccd-eb2a-4a93-9be3-363b83cd3b21",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {}
      },
      {
        "_index": "locationtracking____sampleindex",
        "_type": "user",
        "_id": "42482b3b-d4c7-4a92-bf59-a4c25d707835",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

.. which returns the (correct) set of User(Ids) Hits for Users with TrackedLocations in the past day at the given location. Perfect!

I'll stick with this solution for now over the Aggregations one.. it comes at the "cost" of a parent/child relationship in ES, but overall it does seem more logical.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question - after diving into ES's Aggregations, I found the following solution (via NEST) the most practical & stripped down version that delivers exactly what I wanted above:

```
var userIdsAggregationForLast24HoursAndLocation = elasticClient.Search<BlogPost>(postSearch => postSearch
                .Index(indexName)
                .MatchAll()
                .Source(false)
                .TrackScores(false)
                .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(aggregationDescriptor => aggregationDescriptor
                    .Filter("trackedLocationsFromThePast24HoursAtGivenLocation", descriptor => descriptor
                        .Filter(filterDescriptor => filterDescriptor
                            .And(
                                combinedFilter => combinedFilter
                                    .Range(dateRangeFilter => dateRangeFilter
                                        .GreaterOrEquals(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1))) // filter on instances created/indexed in the past 24 hours
                                        .OnField(trackedLocation => trackedLocation.CreatedAtUtc)),
                                combinedFilter => combinedFilter // and the second filter here is the GeoDistance one.. 1km away from a given .Location(...,...)
                                    .GeoDistance(trackedLocation => trackedLocation.Location, geoDistanceFilterDescriptor => geoDistanceFilterDescriptor
                                        .Distance(1, GeoUnit.Kilometers)
                                        .Location(37.809860, -122.476995)
                                        .Optimize(GeoOptimizeBBox.Indexed))))
                        .Aggregations(userIdAggregate => userIdAggregate.Terms("userIds", userIdTermsFilter => userIdTermsFilter
                            .Field(trackedLocation => trackedLocation.UserId)
                            .Size(100)))))); // get X distinct .UserIds
```

All that really matters is the nested Aggregation(s):

- The first one is an .And() Combined Filter aggregation with its first part being a DateTime Range filter (only the past 24hours are relevant in this case), the second a GeoDistance Filter (I want only instances at a given Location).
- The second, nested .Aggregation of the .Filter() one above is the .Terms() one that delivers the actual UserIds

The raw example request looks like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "track_scores": false,
  "_source": {
    "exclude": [
      "*"
    ]
  },
  "aggs": {
    "trackedLocationsFromThePast24HoursAtGivenLocation": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "range": {
                "createdAtUtc": {
                  "gte": "2015-07-18T07:25:05.992"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "location": "37.80986, -122.476995",
                "distance": 1.0,
                "unit": "km",
                "optimize_bbox": "indexed"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "userIds": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "userId",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

.. and ES's raw response is e.g. like this one:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 100,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "trackedLocationsFromThePast24HoursAtGivenLocation": {
      "doc_count": 12,
      "userIds": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "0a50c2b4-17f0-41bc-b380-f8fca8ca117c",
            "doc_count": 5
          },
          {
            "key": "6b59efd8-a1f9-43c4-86a1-8560b908705f",
            "doc_count": 5
          },
          {
            "key": "667fb1c9-4c9c-4570-8bc1-f61d72e4385f",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "73e93ec8-622b-42e3-8a1c-96a0a2b3b2b2",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, in this example there were 100 tracked locations total, 12 of those tracked locations were created & indexed in the past day by a total of 4 different User(Ids)... two created 5 each, the other 2 created one location each.

That is/was exactly what I expected. I don't really care about scores or the sources/documents themselves, as stated above I only care about the TrackedLocations that fall into the filter and from those I want the distinct list of UserIds.